# I want to create an illustrated book and need help figuring out the cost

Tags: artwork

Instead of "info dumping" in my novel, I've decided to create a companion book similar to the Dinotopia picture books as a reference to use alongside my novel. Now I need help working out the cost.

My questions are:

- What type of people do I need to employ to help create this?
- Or are there already established businesses that do this whom I can approach?

I want to kickstart the project as I cannot afford an illustrator to create maps, family house crests, faction banners, landscapes, kingdoms, characters; some want up to £500 a page plus royalties. I think I've settled on one particular illustrator who is in the middle.

Comment: What is unclear is that on the one hand you seem to have decided to use Kickstarter and have settled on one particular illustrator, and yet you ask what people or businesses you need to approach. It seems to me that the second half of your question alread answers your first half: the illustrator and Kickstarter are who you need to employ. Could you clarify?

Comment: Yeah what else do you need to know? You know how to hire someone to produce illustrations either on paper or as electronic images. There are lots of print on demand companies that specialise in art books, photo books, and illustrated books. You can do everything yourself, or contract different parts out: do you need a book designer, someone to invent maps and heraldic emblems or liaise with artists, someone to format and prepare it for publication, an editor, someone to advise you on what kind of illustrations you need, do you need to find a publisher or printer, or what?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to find good illustrators cheap is [Fiverr](https://www.fiverr.com).

I have used them for fiction, but mostly for business.

Find an artist you like there, make sure they can speak English (or whatever common language you prefer), and do the projects on a one-picture-at-a-time basis.

I did that for a business presentation with over 30 separate images, and it looked great. I got what I wanted, I got edits when I needed them, and the Fiverr was happy and I was happy. (In particular because I always tip 20%, consider that part of the price. They are more willing to work with you if you tip consistently).

But I got my images for about $50 US each. No Royalties, all rights. And I considered my artist to be truly excellent, I would describe what I was looking for in several paragraphs, and she seldom missed anything. There were multiple characters in every picture.

And my presentation was great.

I have also used Fiverr for logos, and illustrations in technical manuals.

I have no financial interest whatsoever in Fiverr; it is just a useful tool for getting piece work of all kinds done, from programming to art, music, AI work, and on and on.

I would not use anyone else, and if you gig it out one pic at a time, it is easy to test an artist and see whether you want to use them for all. You can also see samples of their work, look at their ratings, etc.